# add pulse animation effect to map marker angular agm

Tags: angular, google-maps

I want to add this pulse animation to my markers in angular. I am using [agm](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmmarker) library to add google maps to my project. how can I use css to add this [pulse animation](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/108438303504562416/?lp=true) to my markers?
here is what I have tried until now:

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="mapReading()" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="customTheme">
  <span class="pulse" *ngFor="let marker of markers">
    <agm-marker  [animation]="userLocationMarkerAnimation" [latitude]="marker.lat"
      [longitude]="marker.long" [iconUrl]="marker.icon">
    </agm-marker>
  </span>
</agm-map>
```

here is my css:

```
.pulse {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 64);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7), 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7);
  }

  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7);
  }

  80% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 30px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0);
  }

  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 30px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth to add StackBlitz or share a GitHub project

Comment: I'm just thinking out load here but could you create an [angular animation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) and add that to the `[animation]=""` on the `agm-marker` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps v3 has provided two types of animations out of the box (viz. 'BOUNCE' and 'DROP'). Ref - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Accordingly AGM also has provided the same which you can apply by setting animation input property.

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="mapReading()" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="customTheme">
    <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers" [animation]="userLocationMarkerAnimation" [latitude]="marker.lat"
      [longitude]="marker.long" [iconUrl]="marker.icon">
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

But if you want to apply custome css animations to markers you will have to create markers as custom overlays using `OverlayView`. Ref - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

and

https://www.sitepoint.com/animated-google-map-markers-css-javascript/

With AGM you can create custom overlays using `agm-overlays`. You can find the installation and uses guide here. - https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-overlays

Following is a very simple example using your custom css -

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-overlay [latitude]  = "lat" [longitude] = "lng" >
      <div class="pulse"><img src="{{myIcon}}" height="40" width="40"></div>
  </agm-overlay>
</agm-map>
```

I have created a working sample of the same on stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pypxmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Until you find a proper solution, agm has given two animations,

BOUNCE and DROP,

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="mapReading()" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]="customTheme">
  <span class="pulse" *ngFor="let marker of markers">
    <agm-marker  animation="BOUNCE " [latitude]="marker.lat"
      [longitude]="marker.long" [iconUrl]="marker.icon">
    </agm-marker>
  </span>
</agm-map>
```